# related to variables

Tags: c#

_Shopid =0;

_forename=””;

_dateofbirth=?

id is int represented  by 0

forename is string represented by double qoutations like ""

how to represent dateof birth

Comment: if you want it nullable use `DateTime?` you could assign null to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are called literals. `0` is an integer literal, and `"this"` is a string literal.

There is no datetime literal in C#, but you can create a DateTime based on integer literals for each part of it (year/month/date, etc).

```
_dateofBirth = new DateTime(2011, 03, 19);
```

Comment: can i put instead of this  DateTime(2011,03,19)  to           DateTime(0001,01,01)

Comment: That's a valid DateTime, but I'm not sure why you would want that. If you are looking to have a nullable DateTime, you can use `Nullable<DateTime> _dateOfBirth`, or shorthand syntax for that is to say `DateTime? _dateOfBirth`. You can then check the `.HasValue` property of the nullable type, and if it's true, you can use the `.Value` property to access the (non-nullable) DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the System.DateTime class.

Comment: that is in business logic layer not in database

Comment: ya i want it nullable ? would you pls tell how to use datetime